# Mongoose _doc property

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Let’s suppose that we have in the database a task stored and we want to delete it and check it's deleted. Everything works fine when I have all the code to access the Database in one module. Like this

**task.spec.js  module**

```
task.doFindByIdAndDelete( id )
 .then (function( deletedTask ){ 
   console.log( JSON.stringify(deletedTask.name, null, 2)) ;
 })
 .fail (function( err ){ 
  console.log( err ) ;
 })
```

**task.js  module**

```
var doFindByIdAndDelete = function(id){
 var deferred;
 deferred = Q.defer();

 TaskModel.findByIdAndRemove(id, function(err, modelDeleted){
  if(err){
    var error = "The model could not be deleted: ";
    deferred.reject(error + err);
  }
  deferred.resolve(modelDeleted);
 });

 return deferred.promise;
};
```

With this code I can print the property 'name' of the ‘deletedTask’ without problems. But it results that the method ‘doFindByIdAndDelete’ works for all the elements in the database and I want to create a master function class that contains all the commons methods, and then ‘task’ will be an instance of this master class. The code is:

**task.spec.js  module**

```
task.doFindByIdAndDelete( id )
 .then (function( deletedTask ){ 
   console.log( JSON.stringify(deletedTask.name, null, 2)) ;
 })
 .fail (function( err ){ 
   console.log( err ) ;
 })
```

**MasterModel.js module**

```
var MasterModel = function(Model){
 this.Model = Model;
};

MasterModel.prototype.doFindByIdAndDelete = function(id){
  var deferred;
  deferred = Q.defer();

  Model.findByIdAndRemove(id, function(err, modelDeleted){
    if(err){
      var error = "The model could not be deleted: ";
      deferred.reject(error + err);
    }
    deferred.resolve(modelDeleted);
  });
  return deferred.promise;
};
```

**task.js  module**

```
var task = new ModelLogic(TaskModel);
```

In this version of the code when I call ‘doFindByIdAndDelete’ from task.spec.js I only can access the name property of deletedTask through the _doc property of the model, like deletedTask._doc.name

This is a bug? Are there something wrong in my code?.  I have seen another posts of people with similar problems like

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mongoose-orm/_doc/mongoose-orm/aq7rwxUnHTE/HoGXj6UTcu4J

but I couldn’t find a solution.
Some ideas !!!

Thanks 
Toni

Comment: I'm sorry. The solution is: this.Model.findByIdAndRemove(id, function(err, modelDeleted){…

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  You should either post your solution as an answer (and then accept it) or just delete the question.

Comment: I'm sorry but at the moment of the answer the system didn't let to ask the question I had to wait 24h. But the solution is just add the "this" before 'Model.findByIdAndRemove(id, function(err, modelDeleted){…' just as I detailed in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is just add the "**this**" before '**Model.findByIdAndRemove(id, function(err, modelDeleted){…**' just as I detailed in my comment.

```
this.Model.findByIdAndRemove(id, function(err, modelDeleted){…
```